# C# How to write section of string after being encoded from the ASCII?

Tags: c#, udp, ascii

I have a client UDP where I am retrieving some data. Listening with the UdpClient, I get the string

> "Time=12:34:32, Heartrate=120, Weight=175, Type=cardiacstudy"

I would like just the parts of the string "12:34:32" and "120" to be written and recorded.

I used the code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).IndexOf('=', ','));
```

to try and work something out, but I don't know how to section out the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string by `,` then by `=` and extract the key value pairs :

```
var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
var data = result.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Trim().Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);

Console.WriteLine("Time: " + data["Time"]);
Console.WriteLine("Heartrate: " + data["Heartrate"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `string.Split` like this.

```
    string[] Parse(string raw)
    {
        return raw.Split(new char[] { '=', ',' });
    }
```

the "Time" and "Heartrate" values are in index `[1]` and `[3]`